# how do i add a menu above uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I would like to add a menu like the the one included in the iOS Phone app below.

Whats the best way to go about it.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to do this programmatically or in Interface Builder?

Comment: Whatever works. using storyboards right now. Would UISegmentedControl *mySegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:@[@"Red",@"Green",@"Blue"]]; be an option?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

The screenshot you posted does not have a menu at the top. It's probably a navigation bar with a segmented control in it.

You can make the root view controller of your app a navigation controller, and then push a view controller containing your table view onto the navigation controller.

In the view controller containing the table view you can add a segmented control to the view controller's navigation item.

You might not need a navigation controller and navigation controller though. You could simply lay out a view controller with a table view, and a segmented control above it.